# Saving data in database using hibernate and commit()

Tags: java, hibernate, java-ee-7

I am creating restful api in java EE.

I have defined

```
private static Session session = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
private static org.hibernate.Transaction  tx = session.beginTransaction();
```

in class and in method i am calling

```
Person n  = new Person( getPersonId() , name);
          session.save(n); 
          tx.commit();
```

however commit() closes transaction , and without commit the data wont be saved in database. What is the optimal way to saving data in database without using commit? This leads to creting new transaction on every request which is slow.

Comment: *This leads to creting new transaction on every request which is slow*: no, it's not slow. Get that out of your head.

Comment: Also, if you're using a Java EE container, then you should be using JPA, and declarative transaction handling. Starting and committing hibernate transactions by yourself is precisely one of the key things Java EE allows avoiding.

Answer (score 0):

Try not using transaction and commit. Use flush after save.

Comment: session.save(n); session.flush(); this will not create a sql transaction but should insert n register.